# What's the connection between differential equations and eigenfunctions/eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

I've read differential equations can be understood as "eigenproblems" (using linear algebra concepts, basically), but I'm struggling to see just how.

Could somebody help me out in this? I'm aware it's a very general question, but even a book suggestion or online reference would do wonders for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you taken a course of Differential equations? Because that answers your question.

Comment: E.g. you might look at [these notes of mine](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/eigen/eigen.html)

Comment: $x'=Ax,x(0)=x_0$ is easy to solve if $x_0$ is an eigenvector of $A$ because each component satisfies the 1D ODE $x'=\lambda x$. We build the general solution to $x'=Ax$ this way, taking advantage of the superposition principle. In the process we can also solve nth order linear ODEs with constant coefficients (since these are just a special case of $x'=Ax$, after a suitable change of variable). Linear ODEs with nonconstant coefficients can have the same property (but finding the eigenfunctions is more difficult).